# Variable in script block not getting passed to the rest of my code using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In my code $CoName won't always be perfect and will need adjusted slightly. $CoFixes fixes this issue. But when I run it as shown below, $CoName never makes it to $cell. I need to reuse the code in $CoFixes quite a few times so I'm trying to learn how to make this work.

```
$CoFixes = {
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 10' Panel w/o lath"){$CoName = "L.F. of 10' Panel w/o lath"}
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 9' Panel w/o lath"){$CoName = "L.F. of 9' Panel w/o lath"}
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"){$CoName = "L.F. of 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"}
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 4' Panel w/o lath"){$CoName = "L.F. of 4' Panel w/o lath"}
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"){$CoName = "L.F. of 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"}
if ($CoName -eq 'Special Window Openings over 27"'){$CoName = 'Special Window Openings over 37"'}
if ($CoName -eq 'Door Opening up to 41.5" wide'){$CoName = 'Door Opening up to 41 1/2" wide'}
}

$CoName = $ChangeOrder1Worksheet.range('B20').text
&$CoFixes
$cell = $QuoteSheet.range('B1:B60').Find($CoName).offset(0, 3).address(0,0)
$value = $ChangeOrder1Worksheet.range('A20').text
&$vba
$objExcel.run("ChangeOrder", $cell, $value)
write-host $CoName " " $cell " " $value " " $QuoteSheet.range($cell).text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a scope issue. Variables in a parent scope are accessible from a child scope, but once you write to them, they are copied into the local scope and that's what you are modifying.

Treat this anonymous function you're creating as a function, and return the value instead:

```
$CoFixes = {
if ($CoName -eq "L.F. 10' Panel w/o lath"){"L.F. of 10' Panel w/o lath"}
elseif ($CoName -eq "L.F. 9' Panel w/o lath"){"L.F. of 9' Panel w/o lath"}
elseif ($CoName -eq "L.F. 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"){"L.F. of 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"}
elseif ($CoName -eq "L.F. 4' Panel w/o lath"){"L.F. of 4' Panel w/o lath"}
elseif ($CoName -eq "L.F. 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"){"L.F. of 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"}
elseif ($CoName -eq 'Special Window Openings over 27"'){'Special Window Openings over 37"'}
elseif ($CoName -eq 'Door Opening up to 41.5" wide'){'Door Opening up to 41 1/2" wide'}
else { $CoName }
}

$CoName = $ChangeOrder1Worksheet.range('B20').text
$CoName = &$CoFixes
```

To make that more idiomatic, try a switch:

```
$CoFixes = {
    switch($CoName)
    {
        "L.F. 10' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 10' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 9' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 9' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 8'2`" Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 4' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 4' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath" {"L.F. of 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"}
        'Special Window Openings over 27"' {'Special Window Openings over 37"'}
        'Door Opening up to 41.5" wide' {'Door Opening up to 41 1/2" wide'}
        default { $Name }
    }
}

$CoName = $ChangeOrder1Worksheet.range('B20').text
$CoName = &$CoFixes
```

Then maybe put it in a real function:

```
function Repair-CoName {
    param(
        [String]
        $Name
    )

    switch($Name)
    {
        "L.F. 10' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 10' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 9' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 9' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 8'2`" Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 8'2`" Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 4' Panel w/o lath" {"L.F. of 4' Panel w/o lath"}
        "L.F. 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath" {"L.F. of 4' Panel w/ 8`" top w/o lath"}
        'Special Window Openings over 27"' {'Special Window Openings over 37"'}
        'Door Opening up to 41.5" wide' {'Door Opening up to 41 1/2" wide'}
        default { $CoName }
    }
}

$CoName = $ChangeOrder1Worksheet.range('B20').text
$CoName = Repair-CoName -Name $CoName
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the information. That makes sense to me and helped me get over the hump. It doesn't simply put the code in place instead it acts like a function like you said.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the scoping.

```
$Variable1 = 1
& {
    $Variable1 = 2 #This will create a new local variable and visible only inside the scriptblock
    "Local variable is $Variable1"
    "Global Variable is $Global:Variable1"  
}
```

Execute above script, you can easily understand.